# Deleting Rows in Dataframe After Exploding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that originally looked like this:

```
|student_name|subject                    |
|------------|---------------------------|
|smith       |['maths', 'english']       |
|jones       |['maths', 'english']       |
|alan        |['art', 'maths', 'english']|
```

I used explode to get the following table:

```
|student_name|subject|
|------------|-------|
|smith       |maths  |
|smith       |english|
|jones       |maths  |
|jones       |english|
|alan        |art    |
|alan        |maths  |
|alan        |english|
```

I then reset the index as I want to delete all rows containing the string 'maths'. However, instead of just deleting the rows containing maths it deletes all rows as if they hadn't been exploded/reindexed.

Here's my code:

```
student_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
student_df = student_df.explode('subject')
student_df = student_df.reset_index(drop=True)
student_df = student_df[student_df["subject"].str.contains("maths") == False]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Just use: `student_df.query('subject != "maths"')` . This is quite intuitive and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is to avoid multiple assignments and to use a pipeline.

A few remarks:

- You can pass a function/lambda to `loc` to refer to the dataframe itself.
- Use `~` to invert the value of `str.contains`.
- if you want to check for exact match, do not use `str.contains` but `eq`/`ne` (equal/not equal).

```
student_df2 = (student_df
 .explode('subject')
 .loc[lambda d: ~d['subject'].str.contains("maths")]
)
```

output:

```
  student_name  subject
0        smith  english
1        jones  english
2         alan      art
2         alan  english
```

Comment: OP says *However, instead of just deleting the rows containing maths it deletes all rows as if they hadn't been exploded/reindexed.*, your output is exactly the same with what his code produces.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I read it the other way around, that OP does **not** want to remove all. OP should provide the full explicit output for clarity